# How to use SQLModel with more than 1 database?

Tags: python, fastapi, sqlmodel

I have a FastAPI project using SQLModel as the orm.  I would like to use multiple different databases in the same project.  For example I would like one FastAPI endpoint to query 1 database and another FastAPI endpoint to query a completely different database.  However I'm struggling to find any documentation on how to go about doing so.  I'm assuming it involves a particular setup of the SQLModel classes/engines along with the metadata but I'm unsure. Any direction at all would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying a database is done via a `Session` instance. That session object is instantiated by providing the database `Engine` object, which you typically get by calling the `create_engine` constructor. That constructor takes the database URI as its first argument. I see no problem just setting up two different engines like this:

```py
engine_a = create_engine("sqlite:///a.db", echo=True)
engine_b = create_engine("sqlite:///b.db", echo=True)
```

If you want to have the same tables in both databases, you can just issue the `create_all` call for both engines:

```py
SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine_a)
SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine_b)
```

If you actually want your databases to house **different tables**, you should probably take care in setting up your migration logic appropriately. I assume for a serious project, you'll be using something like alembic for that. But for a quick test, you can even issue individual `CREATE TABLE` statements depending on your needs. Say you want model `A` to map only to the database connected to via `engine_a`, then you could do this:

```py
A.__table__.create(engine_a)
```

For querying you can use the session context just the same as always, but pass the correct engine to it:

```py
with Session(engine_a) as session:
    ...
```

Here is a full working example:

```py
from typing import Optional

from sqlmodel import Field, Session, SQLModel, create_engine


class A(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True)
    foo: str


class B(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(primary_key=True)
    bar: str


if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine_a = create_engine("sqlite:///a.db", echo=True)
    engine_b = create_engine("sqlite:///b.db", echo=True)

    A.__table__.create(engine_a)
    B.__table__.create(engine_b)

    with Session(engine_a) as session:
        session.add(A(foo="abc"))
        session.commit()

    with Session(engine_b) as session:
        session.add(B(bar="xyz"))
        session.commit()
```

You can open the resulting `a.db` and `b.db` in something like [`sqlitebrowser`](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) to see that table `A` with its entry were actually created  only in `a.db`, whereas table `B` with its entry are only in `b.db`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This really helps.  I'm just getting started with this whole SQLModel/FastAPI ecosystem.  I know alembic is for helping with migrations, but could you expand a bit on how that might help this particular case of wanting to have one fastapi project where I have different endpoints hitting different DBs depending on what they are doing? Thanks.